# Finding mode of an Array in O(nlogn) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am asked to find mode of an array in O(nlogn). I can find it in O(n) time but couldn't think another way to be in O(nlogn). Should I use a randomized algorithm? (Is my O(n) solution wrong). My O(n) solution is similar to counting sort algorithm.

Comment: I think you mean "node" of an array, not "mode"

Comment: Show us your code.  O(n) is in O(n logn). That means you already have a solution.

Comment: My array in not an integer array. So, my method does not work :(

Comment: Please explain what "mode of an array" is.

Comment: The mode of A is the value that occurs most frequently in the array. Sorry for missing information.

Comment: @MrSmith42 But my solution works on only integer arrays. I need a solution for any comparable object array working in O(nlogn) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sort the elements of the array  **O(n log n)**
2. iterate through the array and count the number of equal adjacent elements. The highest count is the mode. **O(n)**

So together it takes **O(n log n)** time

Comment: Can I use a monte carlo algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

By that handy graph there you will see that:

- O(n) is better performance than O(n log n)
- Any algorithm that satisfies worst-case O(n) satisfies worst-case O(n log n)

My guess is that the question you originally proposed did not think of a slightly better worst-case solution than yours, if your analysis is correct.

Comment: His **O(n)** solution only works for integers not for the required any comparable object . See his comment to the question.